# Problems deleting several rows from SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Good morning, I'm having some issues while trying to delete several rows at the same time from my db. When I debug the app an exception is thrown (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException) and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());

        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        int rowId = c.getInt(0);
        while(c.getCount() > 50)
        {
            db.deleteContact(rowId);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    
        db.close();  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to delete records who have **ID** value greater than **50**.

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();

while(c.moveToNext())
{
    int rowId = c.getInt(0);
    if(rowId > 50){
        db.deleteContact(rowId);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
c.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to limit the number of rows to 50, removing the old entries (the rows with lower _id) but this already helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is here:

```
    int rowId = c.getInt(0);
    while(c.getCount() > 50)
    {
        db.deleteContact(rowId);
```

I don't think the cursor gets to know that one of its rows was deleted while it was still open. So the cursor does not auto-magically remove the deleted row from its "cache", which means trouble when it comes to accessing a row via the cursor that was already deleted.

I recommend to use a single delete statement with an appropriate where clause, which will also help performance.

Maybe like this: Find the first row (minimal rowId) that you want to keep, which is the one that sits 50 rows before the last of your rows. Then you can just perform `delete from ... where _id < minimalRowId`. Have a look at [moveToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29); then you can use `cursor.moveToPosition( cursor.getCount() - 50 )` to find your row of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to pass data in a coma separated string and then write delete query using IN(]multiple id's])

eg,

```
DELETE FROM Persons
WHERE LastName IN ('Person1','Person2',"Person3")
```